# Rasberry Pi 3 Pi4j does not work for digital pins other than RaspiPin.GPIO_07

Tags: raspbian, gpio, java, pi4j

I am trying to get a led working with the **Raspberry Pin 3 model B+** with Raspbian. I am using Java `Pi4j` library this way:

```
GpioPinDigitalOutput digitalOutputPin = GpioFactory.getInstance().provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_07);
GpioFactory.getInstance().setState(true, digitalOutPutPin);
```

It is only working with the `Raspipin.GPIO_07` **not with others** ( `Raspipin.GPIO_11, GPIO_13, GPIO_15, GPIO_16, GPIO_18, GPIO_22, GPIO_29, GPIO_31`). All pins were already unprovisioned, no exceptions are thrown, but the led is not working with other pin other than the Raspipin.GPIO_07.

What does it mean Raspipin.GPIO_07 is 1-wire pin?.

Im not sure If I am following the right pinout schema. The `RaspiPin.GPIO_07` in library is the one labeled as **GPIO4** in the picture below am I right? So the RaspiPin.GPIO_11 should be the one labeled in the picture as the GPIO17.

[image: pinout]

Comment: GPIO4 (physical pin #7) is the 1-wire interface (unless it's disabled). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome.
For some reason (historic that made sense at the time I am sure), the [Pi4J project](https://pi4j.com) followed the WiringPi software for pin layout.  To quote their site:

> Pi4J (by default) uses an abstract pin numbering scheme to help insulate software from hardware changes.
> Pi4J implements the same pin number scheme as the Wiring Pi project

The good news is that the library can be configured to use the Broadcom numbering schemes using:

```
GpioFactory.setDefaultProvider(new RaspiGpioProvider(RaspiPinNumberingScheme.BROADCOM_PIN_NUMBERING));
```

This is a little easier to follow and well documented on lots of sites (e.g. https://pinout.xyz/) and will make more sense to other hardware designers or even language users (e.g. Python).

If you do not want to modify your code, then details of the 3B+ pins are to be found [here](https://pi4j.com/1.2/pins/model-3b-plus-rev1.html) on the libraries site and this is taken from there:

[image]